# Android Aspect Ratio of Button

Tags: android, button, scale, aspect-ratio

I use the following to display a button in a layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/butt2"
            android:onClick="clk_clear"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

    </TableRow>

   </LinearLayout>
```

This sets the layout to 20% of the available height and place a button within

Problem is when 20% of the screen is smaller than the height of the icon in squeezes it vertically but doesn't keep aspect ratio so a circle ends up looking like an oval

UPDATE

I Tried the following but it crashes saying it cannot be cast to

```
 android.widget.TableRow$LayouParams
```

any ideas

```
Button txt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);  
    int btnSize=txt1.getLayoutParams().width;
    txt1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(btnSize, btnSize));
```

Also Tried

```
    Button txt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);  
    int btnSize=txt1.getHeight();
    txt1.setWidth(btnSize);
```

Still looks like an oval

[image: Sample Image]

Solved but Icon is very small Needs to be same size as lines
Mark

[image: Very Small]

[image: Oval]

Comment: According to the documentation, to create an icon for different densities, you should follow the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively). Are you following this? try to follow the above and use different sized icons

Comment: do you mean I have to put the png shrunk to relevant size in each folder? My png is in a folder call res/drawable and not in the repective folders

Comment: Yes, for example in xhdpi folder, put 96x96 and in hdpi folder put 72x72 image, with same name.

Comment: Which device you are testing in, or which emulator dpi you use?

Comment: nexus 10 emulator and galaxy note 10. tablet both have quad screens but trying to get the icon to be the same ratio on all screens

Comment: I have added a picture above See how small the icon is I want it to be the size where the 2 lines are if I do Match_parent on the height it does fill to the lines but the width is not affected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68176/discussion-between-eagleeye-and-user3422687).

Answer (score 1):

You are not using icons or images according to the documentation. Since you are targeting Tablets, they may fall under HDPI,XHDPI or XXHDPI. Make sure you have same image with same name in respective resource folder with different size.

Generally the resource folder structure is as follows
[image]

You can read more on this on
http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

The documentation clearly says,

When your app runs, Android checks the characteristics of the device screen and loads the appropriate density-specific assets for your app. To create an icon for different densities, you should follow the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively). For example, consider that the size for a launcher icon is specified to be 48x48 dp. This means the baseline (MDPI) asset is 48x48 px, and the high-density(HDPI) asset should be 1.5x the baseline at 72x72 px, and the x-high density (XHDPI) asset should be 2x the baseline at 96x96 px, and so on.
 Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer however I have all those folders in my res folder and each one has a corisponding icon at the corect size all with the same name but when ever the app runs it alwways seems to pick the same one which appears to be 48 x 48

Comment: I have added a 2nd picture showing the issue the top layout is 80% of screen height the 2nd layout is 20% of height I want the icon to fill the height of the 20% layout but remain a circle If I use match Parent on the height it works but the width stays the same and results in an oval

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys I couldn't work out how to do this so I have a workaround. I used the following code to detect what size screen the app is installed on and then run a different xml layout depending whether its a phone, phablet or Tablet

Not A perfect solution but unless someone can help me getting this right its the best I could come up with

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
    int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
    String Textsize = String.valueOf(widthPixels) + " x " + String.valueOf(heightPixels);
    float scaleFactor = metrics.density;
    float widthDp = widthPixels / scaleFactor;
    float heightDp = heightPixels / scaleFactor;
    String Textsize2 = String.valueOf(widthDp) + " x " + String.valueOf(heightDp);
    float smallestWidth = Math.min(widthDp, heightDp);
    float widthDpi = metrics.xdpi;
    float heightDpi = metrics.ydpi;
    float widthInches = widthPixels / widthDpi;
    float heightInches = heightPixels / heightDpi;
    double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(
            (widthInches * widthInches) 
            + (heightInches * heightInches));

    if (diagonalInches >= 10) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tablet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity2);
    } 
    if (diagonalInches >= 5 && diagonalInches <=9){
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Phablet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
    } 
    if (diagonalInches <= 5) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity3);
    }
```